# PHP to C# AES encryption does not match

Tags: c#, php, encryption

I'm working to make a call to an API endpoint where it needs encrypted data sent by the client. The sample is in PHP as shown below

```
function OpenSSLEncrypt($message, $key)
{
    $output = false;
    $encrypt_method = "AES-256-CBC";
    $secret_key = $key;
    $secret_iv = $key;
    $key = hash('sha256', $secret_key);
    $iv = substr(hash('sha256', $secret_iv), 0, 16);
    $output = openssl_encrypt($message, $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);
    $output = trim(base64_encode($output));
    return $output;
}
```

I need to convert it to C# but it generates the wrong result and is not the same as the PHP version. The C# mine is like this

```
static byte[] Sha256(string rawData)
        {
            using (SHA256 sha256Hash = SHA256.Create()) return sha256Hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rawData));
        }

static string OpenSSLEncrypt(string plainText, string key)
{
    var bkey = Sha256(key);

    var iv = new byte[16];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(bkey, 0, iv, 0, iv.Length);

    using (RijndaelManaged rijndaelManaged = new RijndaelManaged { Key = bkey, IV = iv, Mode = CipherMode.CBC, Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7 })
    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, rijndaelManaged.CreateEncryptor(rijndaelManaged.Key, rijndaelManaged.IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
    {
        using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(cryptoStream))
        {
            streamWriter.Write(plainText);
        }
        var encrypted = memoryStream.ToArray();
        return Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted);
    }
}
```

php version sample:
key: `f17575bc689c4c43278db9aae0e4ecc2`

cipherText: `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`

plainText:

```
{
  "cms": "WINPAY API",
  "spi_callback": "https://sandbox-payment.winpay.id/sandbox",
  "url_listener": "https://sandbox-payment.winpay.id/sandbox/url_listener.php",
  "spi_currency": "IDR",
  "spi_item": [
    {
      "name": "Baju Bali",
      "sku": "01020304",
      "qty": 2,
      "unitPrice": 20000,
      "desc": "Baju Tidur"
    },
    {
      "name": "Baju Jogja",
      "sku": "01020305",
      "qty": 1,
      "unitPrice": 10000,
      "desc": "Baju Olahraga"
    }
  ],
  "spi_amount": 50000,
  "spi_signature": "38697D628FAF2806FCD1844DC895C50CB631C38E",
  "spi_token": "4d0cba482565a4380286a87848fac6002005607b7ba79d210ef38d1c36b433cc",
  "spi_merchant_transaction_reff": "5e4ce7cf7901234",
  "spi_billingPhone": "081234567777",
  "spi_billingEmail": "tester@gmail.com",
  "spi_billingName": "Tester Winpay",
  "spi_paymentDate": "20211231224623",
  "get_link": "no"
}
```

Comment: The PHP version is not mine. That's the sample provided. So, I need to convert to my C# code

Comment: You didn't show any sample data: plaintext, ciphertext and key. As PHP is filling or trimming too short or long keys that could cause your problem.

Comment: @MichaelFehr I've updated the question

Comment: You didn't post the `Sha256()` method from the C# code. Assuming that this simply provides the hash, the key derivations of the two codes differ because the PHP code uses the _hexadecimal encoded_ hash. For a port to C#, consider that `hash()` uses lowercase and `openssl_encrypt()` truncates keys that are too long. In addition, the PHP code Base64 encodes twice. Btw, key and IV derivation are insecure.

Comment: As expected, `Sha256()` only creates the hash. Adjust the C# code as sketched in my last comment. As example, I would start with a simple plaintext first, so that troubleshooting is not complicated by formatting issues.

Comment: I still have no luck.

Comment: I've solved this issue. As you said, I should change the key to hex value, substring the hex then convert to plain byte array NOT hex byte array